# How can I use bash's if test and find commands together?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, find, test

I have a directory with crash logs, and I'd like to use a conditional statement in a bash script based on a find command.

The log files are stored in this format:

```
/var/log/crashes/app-2012-08-28.log
/var/log/crashes/otherapp-2012-08-28.log
```

I want the if statement to only return true if there is a crash log for a specific app which has been modified in the last 5 minutes. The `find` command that I would use is:

```
find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate that into an `if` statement properly. I think this might work:

```
if [ test `find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5` ] then
 service myapp restart
fi
```

There are a few areas where I'm unclear:

- I've looked at the [if flags](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) but I'm not sure which one, if any, that I should use.
- Do I need the `test` directive or should I just process against the results of the find command directly, or maybe use `find... | wc -l` to get a line count instead?
- Not 100% necessary to answer this question, but `test` is for testing against return codes that commands return? And they are sort of invisible - outside of `stdout` / `stderr`? I read the `man` page but I'm still pretty unclear about when to use `test` and how to debug it.

Comment: The real answer to the *general* case is to use `find ... -exec`.  Also see the example commands under [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard - unfortunately that *doesn't* solve the general case: it doesn't work if there is more than one match and the action needs to only run once, and it doesn't work if you need an action to run when there are no matches.  The former can be solved by using `... -exec command ';' -quit`, but I don't believe there is any solution for the latter other than parsing the result.  Also, in either case, the primary problem with parsing the result of `find` (i.e. inability to distinguish delimiters from characters in filenames) doesn't apply, as you don't need to find delimiters in these cases.

Comment: -exec is good for quick response, but for wider conditions `if find ... | grep .` is better:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684153/43233

Comment: Easier to check systemd status, or if the process is running

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`[` and `test` are synonyms (except `[` requires `]`), so you don't want to use `[ test`:

```
[ -x /bin/cat ] && echo 'cat is executable'
test -x /bin/cat && echo 'cat is executable'
```

`test` returns a zero exit status if the condition is true, otherwise nonzero. This can actually be replaced by any program to check its exit status, where 0 indicates success and non-zero indicates failure:

```
# echoes "command succeeded" because echo rarely fails
if /bin/echo hi; then echo 'command succeeded'; else echo 'command failed'; fi

# echoes "command failed" because rmdir requires an argument
if /bin/rmdir; then echo 'command succeeded'; else echo 'command failed'; fi
```

However, all of the above examples only test against the program's exit status, and ignore the program's output.

For `find`, you will need to test if any output was generated. `-n` tests for a non-empty string:

```
if [[ -n $(find /var/log/crashes -name "app-*.log" -mmin -5) ]]
then
    service myapp restart
fi
```

A full list of test arguments is available by invoking `help test` at the `bash` commandline.

<sub>If you are using `bash` (and not `sh`), you can use `[[ condition ]]`, which behaves more predictably when there are spaces or other special cases in your condition. Otherwise it is generally the same as using `[ condition ]`. I've used `[[ condition ]]` in this example, as I do whenever possible.</sub>

<sub>I also changed `` `command` `` to `$(command)`, which also generally behaves similarly, but is nicer with nested commands.</sub>

Comment: `echo` can fail: try `echo 'oops' > /dev/full`.

Comment: This answer beats all around the root of the problem but gracefully avoids mentioning exactly what that is.

Comment: @bahamat: And how does your cmt improve things? If you have something to say, please - say it.

Answer (score 14):

`find` will exit successfully if there weren't any errors, so you can't count on its exit status to know whether it found any file. But, as you said, you can count how many files it found and test that number.

It would be something like this:

```
if [ $(find /var/log/crashes -name 'app-*.log' -mmin -5 | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

`test` (aka `[`) doesn't check the error codes of the commands, it has a special syntax to do tests, and then exits with an error code of 0 if the test was successful, or 1 otherwise. It is `if` the one that checks the error code of the command you pass to it, and executes its body based on it.

See `man test` (or `help test`, if you use `bash`), and `help if` (ditto).

In this case, `wc -l` will output a number. We use `test`'s option `-gt` to test if that number is greater than `0`. If it is, `test` (or `[`) will return with exit code `0`. `if` will interpret that exit code as success, and it will run the code inside its body.

Answer (score 2):

This would be

```
if [ -n "$(find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5)" ]; then
```

or

```
if test -n "$(find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5)"; then
```

The commands `test` and `[ … ]` are exactly synonymous. The only difference is their name, and the fact that `[` requires a closing `]` as its last argument. As always, use double quotes around the command substitution, otherwise the output of the `find` command will be broken into words, and here you'll get a syntax error if there is more than one matching file (and when there are no arguments, `[ -n ]` is true, whereas you want `[ -n "" ]` which is false).

In ksh, bash and zsh but not in ash, you can also use `[[ … ]]` which has different parsing rules: `[` is an ordinary command, whereas `[[ … ]]` is a different parsing construct. You don't need double quotes inside `[[ … ]]` (though they don't hurt). You still need the `;` after the command.

```
if [[ -n $(find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5) ]]; then
```

This can potentially be inefficient: if there are many files in `/var/log/crashes`, find will explore them all. You should make find stop as soon as it finds a match, or soon after. With GNU find (non-embedded Linux, Cygwin), use the `-quit` primary.

```
if [ -n "$(find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5 -print -quit)" ]; then
```

With other systems, pipe `find` into `head` to at least quit soon after the first match (find will die of a broken pipe).

```
if [ -n "$(find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5 -print | head -n 1)" ]; then
```

(You can use `head -c 1` if your `head` command supports it.)

---

Alternatively, use zsh.

```
crash_files=(/var/log/crashes/**/app-*.log(mm-5[1]))
if (($#crash_files)); then
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```sh
if find /var/log/crashes -name 'app-\*\.log' -mmin -5 | read
then
  service myapp restart
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /var/log/crashes -name app-\*\.log -mmin -5 -exec service myapp restart ';' -quit
```

is an appropriate solution here.

`-exec service myapp restart ';'` causes `find` to invoke the command that you want to run directly, rather than needing the shell to interpret anything.

`-quit` causes `find` to exit after processing the command, thus preventing the command being executed again if there happen to be multiple files that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the output of find into a variable, and then using bash's test, to handle the different cases you're interested in. The simple case is whether there are any results or not:

```
mycrashedapp=$(find /var/log/crashes/ -name myapp-\*\.log -mmin -5)
# if no crash then the variable is empty
if [[ -z "${mycrashedapp}" ]];then
  echo "myapp is behaving."
else
  service myapp restart
fi
```

At this point, you can do further handling, if needed, using bash's variable manipulation:

```
substr="/var/log/crashes"
parse=${mycrashedapp//"$substr"}
myappcrashedcount="$(((${#mycrashedapp} - ${#parse}) / ${#substr}))"

echo "myapp has crashed ${myappcrashedcount} times in total."
```

You can do further processing with bash's builtin regex pattern matching:

```
if [[ "${mycrashedapp}" =~ myapp-([0-9\-]*).log ]]; then
  echo "The dates and times that myapp has crashed:"
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Piping the find command to `grep .` would **print the find results**, in addition to the if condition response:

```
if find -name "*.log" | grep . ; then echo Found; else echo Nothing; fi
```

> ./home/nmanos/2709.log
> ./home/nmanos/5816.log
> ./home/nmanos/1643.log
> Found

And when nothing is found:

```
if find -name "*.gol" | grep . ; then echo Found; else echo Nothing; fi
```

> Nothing

Comment: Use `grep -q .` to avoid printing and to terminate at the first match.