# Bash: "too many arguments" in IF-THEN statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am attempting to check if a specific file exists (but only if less than 24 hours old), and if so, perform a second check to see if a file with a name ending in ".control" exists. If both of these conditions are met then create an email and log entry. If the first file exists but the .control does not, then make a different log entry. If the file less than 24 hours old doesn't exist, then continue with the rest of the script.

This is in a shell script launched from cron using Bash on Solaris and Linux.

```
if [ find "$MAINTENANCE_LOCK/testLOCK" -mtime -1 ]; then
    if [ -f "$PATH_TO_TRIGGER_FILES/*.control" ]; then
        test_log_msg "test_SYSTEM" $NOTICE "Valid Maintenance Lock file found, test actions blocked." "status"
        test_log_email " " " " " " "test Actions were blocked because an testLOCK file less than 24hrs old is in place." " "
    else
        test_log_msg "test_SYSTEM" $NOTICE "Valid Maintenance Lock file in place." "status"
        exit
    fi
fi
```

However when I step through the lines of the code with "set -x
trap read debug" I get the following error:

```
+ '[' find /var/opt/test/maintenancelock/testLOCK -mtime -1 ']'
/opt/test/test_control.sh: line 72: [: too many arguments
```

Is there a way to do what I want here?

Comment: Related: [How can I use bash's if test and find commands together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46541/how-can-i-use-bashs-if-test-and-find-commands-together)

Comment: I think maybe you want something like `if [ -n "$(find "$MAINTENANCE_LOCK/testLOCK" -mtime -1)" ] ; then` ... Putting `find` directly inside `[...]` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: `if [ -f "$PATH_TO_TRIGGER_FILES/*.control" ]` probably isn't what you want either, unless the file literally should have an asterisk in its name. You could do something similar to the other conditional. `if [ -n "$(find "$PATH_TO_TRIGGER_FILES" -name '*.control')" ] ; then `

Answer (score 5):

Try `help [` then `help test` -- `[` is a synonym for `test`, and the `test` help says:

> The behavior of test depends on the number of arguments.

With this: `[ find "$MAINTENANCE_LOCK/testLOCK" -mtime -1 ];`
you're passing 4 words to `[`, and it doesn't know what to do with 4 arguments.

---

> I am attempting to check if a specific file exists (but only if less than 24 hours old), and if so, perform a second check to see if a file with a name ending in ".control" exists.

With bash:

```bash
mapfile -t testlock < <(find "$MAINTENANCE_LOCK/testLOCK" -mtime -1)
if [[ ${#testlock[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "lock file does no exist or is too old"
else
    control=( "$PATH_TO_TRIGGER_FILES/"*.control )
    if [[ ${#control[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo "lock file exists and at least one control file exists"
    else
        echo "lock file exists but no control files exist"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You can devise valid expressions for `test` with exactly 4 arguments, but you'd need `-a` or `-o` to combine 2 expressions.

Comment: I tried to implement this solution and I get the following error on Solaris:
Sending status message to user
grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep [-c|-l|-q] -bhinsvw pattern file . . .

Comment: I don't see `grep` in my answer. Maybe you need to ask a separate question.

Comment: Technically, `[ find "..." -mtime -1 ];` passes _5_ words to `[`, namely `find`, `"..."`, `-mtime`, `-1`, _and `]`_.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command is supposed to return several files, hence the warning you see.

If you want check one file, it would be better to use `stat`

```
file_btime=$(stat -c%W /var/opt/test/maintenancelock/testLOCK)
time_now=$(date %s)
file_age=$(( time_now - file_btime ))

if [ $file_age -le 86400 ] ; then
   echo File is less then 24h old
fi
```

Comment: ctime is not creation time. You probably want mtime

Comment: The "Solaris and Linux" part is tricky: is that `stat` invocation valid on Solaris?

Comment: @roaima, `mtime` is modification time, `ctime` or more specifically "birth time" is a time when file was created. For lock files, the ctime is more useful (usually). But if you like to do an `mtime` - replace `-c%W` with `-c%Y`.

Comment: @WhiteOwl `ctime` is the change time which refers to the last time some metadata related to the file was changed. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time)

Comment: The `find` command is never being executed, it doesn't matter what it returns. The `[` command doesn't execute its arguments as a command.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `find` always returns true (0), whether it finds a matching file or not.

However, using the `-exec` predicate to run `/bin/false` on matching file(s), you can get it to return false (1) if it finds one or more matches.  Testing the negation (`!`) of that will be true if found, false otherwise.

For example:

```bash
# does the lock file exist?
if ! find "$MAINTENANCE_LOCK/testLOCK" -mtime -1 -exec false {} + ; then
  # are there any .control files?
  if ! find "$PATH_TO_TRIGGER_FILES" -name '*.control' -exec false {} + ; then
    test_log_msg "test_SYSTEM" $NOTICE "Valid Maintenance Lock file found, test actions blocked." "status"
    test_log_email " " " " " " "test Actions were blocked because an testLOCK file less than 24hrs old is in place." " "
  else
    test_log_msg "test_SYSTEM" $NOTICE "Valid Maintenance Lock file in place." "status"
    exit
  fi
fi
```

If you do this a lot, or just want your script to be more-readable/self-documenting, you could wrap it in a function:

```bash
file_exists () {
  # The args to this function are passed directly to find,
  # so anything that works with find will work here.
  # And anything that breaks find will break this function too.
  # Also, you probably don't want to use any find arguments that
  # produce any output.

  if ! find "$@" -exec false {} + ; then
    # one or more matching files were found, return true
    return 0
  else
    # nothing found, return false
    return 1
  fi
}

if file_exists "$MAINTENANCE_LOCK/testLOCK" -mtime -1 ; then
  if file_exists "$PATH_TO_TRIGGER_FILES" -name '*.control' ; then
    ...
  else
    ...
  fi
fi
```

---

Note that `/bin/false` completely ignores its argument(s), it just returns an exit code of false (1) no matter how many args it has...so this is useful if you only need to test for existence but **NOT** useful if you need to **count** the number of matching files.  If you needed to do that, you could do something like (with GNU find or any other find that supports `-printf`):

```bash
if [ "$(find . -mtime -1 -printf 1 | wc -c)" -gt 10 ] ; then
  : do something here
fi
```

This prints a single character for each file found (it doesn't matter which character is printed - I'm using "1" here, but it would work the same for "." or "x" or any other char), and then counts them with `wc -c`.  If there are more than 10, then the `if` test evaluates as true.

For a non-GNU `find` without `-printf` that supports the (also non-POSIX, but still quite common) `-print0` option, you could use:

```bash
if [ "$(find . -mtime -1 -print0 | awk -v RS='\0' 'END{print NR}')" -gt 10 ] ; then
  : do something here
fi
```

This version uses `awk` to print the number of NUL-separated records (i.e. the number of matching files) in `find`'s output.

If you are absolutely certain that **none** of the file or directory names will ever contain a newline (`\n`) character, then you could just use the POSIX standard `-print` instead of `-print0` (and pipe into `wc -l`) - but that is never something you can rely on because you can never really be absolutely certain that such a filename will never exist at some point in the future.  i.e. at best, it might work now but could fail tomorrow, or next year.